# Infix/Postfix evaluator terminating issue

Tags: c++, function, infix-notation, postfix-mta

I've got a few different functions that on their own work fine. Now I am trying to put them together into one file. My debugger is throwing segmentation faults in the `infixToPostfix` function.

When I watch the `ns` variable, it does not show anything getting assigned to it, but it prints out the postfix expression when I actually run the code. When `ns` passes into `PostfixEvaulation`, it runs to the `top` member function of `TemplateStack` and crashes with:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of "std::string"`

This only happens when I pass a string with an operator. When I pass a string of just numbers, everything runs fine, 
but it still does not seem to call `PostfixEvaluation`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

//Class Template Stack declaration
template <class T>
class TemplateStack {
public:
    typedef T type;
    TemplateStack()
    {
        max_size_ = 50;
        TopOfStack = 0;
        data_ = new T[max_size_];
    } //Default Constructor taking no parameters
    void push(T element)
    {
        if (TopOfStack == max_size_)
            throw string("Stack's underlying storage is overflow");
        TopOfStack++;
        data_[TopOfStack] = element;
    }
      void pop() {
            if (TopOfStack == -1)
                  throw string("Stack is empty");
            TopOfStack--;
      }


      T top() {
            if (TopOfStack == -1)
                  throw string("Stack is empty");
            return data_[TopOfStack];
     }

private:
    int TopOfStack; //Generic data type for the top element of stack
    size_t max_size_;
    T* data_;
};

 //Function to Evauluate the Postfix notation expresion
int PostfixEvaulation(string input){
    //string input;
    int operand1, operand2, result,number;
    TemplateStack<char>operation;
    stringstream temp;
    int i=0;
    while (i < input.length())
    {
        if (isdigit(input[i]))
        {
            operation.push(input[i]);
        }
        else
        {
          operand2 = operation.top();
          temp << operation.top();
          operation.pop();
          operand1 = operation.top();
          temp << operation.top();
          operation.pop();
          switch(operand1,operand2)
          {
                  case '+': result=operand1 + operand2;
                  break;
                  case '-': result=operand1 - operand2;
                  break;
                  case '*': result=operand1 * operand2;
                  break;
                  case '/': result=operand1 / operand2;
                  break;
        }
        operation.push(result);
        }
        i++;
    }
    cout << "The result is: "<<temp.str()<<endl;
    //cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    return 0;
}


//Function to return precedence of operators
int prec(char c)
{
    if(c == '^')
    return 3;
    else if(c == '*' || c == '/')
    return 2;
    else if(c == '+' || c == '-')
    return 1;
    else
    return -1;
}

//Function: Convert Infix to Postfix
void infixToPostfix(string s)
{
    TemplateStack<char> st;
    st.push('N');
    int l = s.length();
    string ns;
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        // If the scanned character is an operand, add it to output string.
        if ((s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') || (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')) {
            ns += s[i];
        }
        // If the scanned character is an ‘(‘, push it to the stack.
        else if (s[i] == '(') {

            st.push('(');
        }
        // If the scanned character is an ‘)’, pop and to output string from the stack
        // until an ‘(‘ is encountered.
        else if (s[i] == ')') {
            while (st.top() != 'N' && st.top() != '(') {
                char c = st.top();
                st.pop();
                ns += c;
            }
            if (st.top() == '(') {
                char c = st.top();
                st.pop();
            }
        }
        //If an operator is scanned
        else {
            while (st.top() != 'N' && prec(s[i]) <= prec(st.top())) {
                char c = st.top();
                st.pop();
                ns += c;
            }
            st.push(s[i]);
        }
    }
    //Pop all the remaining elements from the stack
    while (st.top() != 'N') {
        char c = st.top();
        st.pop();
        ns += c;
    }
    cout << "Here is the ns variable: "<< ns << endl;
    PostfixEvaulation(ns);//Call the PostFixEvaluationFunction with the ns (postfix notation) variab
}

 //Function: User inputs Expression
void GetInput(){
    string input;
    cout << "Enter Infix Expression: ";
    getline(cin, input);
    infixToPostfix(input);
}

int main()
{
    GetInput();
}
```

Comment: why do you throw std::string ? throwing a standard error will give you a more descriptive error report

Comment: Your TemplateStack has a problem: it has the `new` operator's call, but has not the `delete`'s one.

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Don't get me wrong, I would also recommend throwing a(n object derived from) standard exception, but how does it make "error report" "more descriptive"?

Comment: @user2079303 because most (all?) RT and debuggers will show the error message while reporting the uncought exception ... I didn't mean to say that's the only ( or most important, if any ) reason to do so, of course

Comment: @SergeRoussak I added a destrcutor with `delete[] data_` but the problem persists. Did I misunderstand what you were getting at?

Comment: the better solution to "new but not delete" is to remove the new rather than to add a delete ;). Why dont you use containers from the std lib? If you you want to write your own stack you could still use a `std::vector` to store the data

Comment: @cparks10, no, you didn't. Simply I wrote about the problem, which is striking.

Comment: In the `PostfixEvaulation` you mix `int` and `char`, which might not work that well. I also don't quite see how `isdigit(input[i])` will work when you seem to have variable names in the string. And `switch(operand1,operand2)` is not a proper way to use a switch-statement - where do you get the operator?

Comment: The first thing you should do is to find out exactly which 'throw' is happening, either by throwing a proper exception type, wrapping your 'main' contents in a try/catch, or telling your debugger to break on exceptions. Only once you know which exception is getting thrown can you begin to try to fix it.
And as @BoPersson says, I'm pretty sure that "switch(operand1,operand2)" is not going to be doing what you think it's doing (if you think it's doing anything other than switching on the value of operand2).

Comment: @SeanBurton when I step through the debugger it gets to line 65 `operand1=operation.top()`, goes to the `top` member function and then terminates.

Comment: Well, what is the only string exception that gets thrown from the 'top' function? The one that says the stack is empty. So your stack is probably empty...